Excel VBA - method .Borders not working with format conditions that not setting the borders
I have write i code that works but has unelegant way to handle FormatCondition that are not changing the borders of cells.
This problem is dealing with line:
If cf.Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
Sometimes it throws me an error saying:
Run-time error 438:
Object doesn't support this property or method

I assume that this happens when f = ws.Cells.FormatConditions(i) has format condition that have nothing to do with setting the borders, so cf.Borders is somehow uninitialized and gives me this error. This is only my guess based on testing. I have multiple format conditions in my sheet that only sets the color of cell.
So i have added On Error Resume Next in my code to skip the cells that gives me this error and my VBA scripts works perfectly fine!
BUT i am not impressed with my solution, because i will be skipping all kinds of different erros in this particular line of code.
How i can handle this error better?
How i can check wether cf.Borders exist before i try to get inside this property?
IF you are curious why cf is a Variant type, please look at:
VBA Type missmatch in For Each loop
Below is my modified working code that i am not happy with:
'=========================================================
' Clear existing conditional formatting with lower borders
'=========================================================


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cf  As Variant ' UniqueValues
    Dim i As Long

    
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Loop through each existing conditional formatting rule backwards to avoid skipping
    For i = ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set cf = ws.Cells.FormatConditions(i)
        
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Check if the conditional formatting rule adds a bottom border
        If cf.Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
        On Error GoTo borderNotInitialized
        ' Clear conditional formatting
            cf.Delete
borderNotInitialized:
            End If
    Next i


FormatConditions can be several different object types - this is the reason you need to define the control variable as Variant.
You can check the real type using typename. The types I am aware of are

"FormatCondition"
"Top10"
"Databar"
"ColorScale"
"IconSetCondition"

Borders are available only for Type "FormatCondition". So change you code to
 If TypeName(cf) = "FormatCondition" Then
    If cf.Borders(xlBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
        cf.Delete
    End If
End If

